# Multiple "not" conditions in prototype $$ CSS selector

Tags: javascript, prototype, sizzle

I'm trying to exclude two cases in my CSS selector. Currently the selector looks like this:

```
$$('select:not([class=session])').each(function(){
    //blah blah
})
```

But i want to exclude another class named "sessionproperties"

Is there any way to exclude more than one in a single selector statement? Any help on this is appreciated.

*note: I've tried using the ~= operator for the word "session" but it totally does not work for me.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you need the class attribute, that is what a `.` selector is for. You can comma separate sub selectors in the `:not` just like you can when you define them in your stylesheet.

```
$$('select:not(.session, .sessionproperties)').each(function() {
 ...
})
```

Comment: lol, so prototype does the same as jQuery. Should have checked that better. =) +1

Comment: @Madison Yep, I'm confident that they all just leverage `document.querySelectorAll` at this point so they'd have to match the w2c specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype supports CSS3 syntax selectors,

So why not try the comma?

```
$$('select:not([class=session]), select:not([class=sessionproperties]').each(function(){
    //blah blah
})
```

Comment: I tried that before I posted this as well. For some reason it breaks the first not() statement as well and just selects all of the <select>s. :/

Comment: i think the OP wanted to remove the union of the two groups, your selection removes the intersection

Comment: hehe. tell all the cs kids in college that its practical and theyll laugh, although here we are